# Pass through bash read interactive?

Tags: bash, shell

I have a bash script which uses a read to save the input in a variable `$INFO`. (user input is for example “yes” or “no”)

My problem is that I’m not allowed to change this script, but I want to execute it interactively from the shell.

Is there a possibility for user to enter the input interactively? 
Other idea that came into my mind, is to set the variables inside the script from outside(remote) the script?

Thanks.

Comment: Look up `expect`

Comment: The read IS interactively. Do you want to feed it automatically/script driven?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! The answer to your question is "Yes, there is a way". Please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for tips on improving this question. In particular, it needs to include the code for your attempt to solve your problem. We are not short order programmers working for free, we are a community of people helping each other improve our craft.

Answer (score 1):

If the script uses `read`, you should be able to just send the input to its stdin:

```
echo $'yes\nno' | script.sh
```

For example:

```
echo $'yes\nno' | (
    for i in 1 2 ; do
        read INFO
        echo You said $INFO
    done
)
```

Output:

```
You said yes
You said no
```

Comment: With this i get a loop of "Please type "yes" or "no":Please type "yes" or "no"" messages and the script will abort.

Comment: @CWollinger: Then I don't understand your requirements.